# Save instance of dynamically generated views when we switch back and forth between activities

Tags: android, android-view

I am inflating a view on button click and the user can add as many views as he likes, all is fine I made it work, but now the problem is when I go back one activity and come again to my dynamically generated activity every single view that was generated is gone. Similar is the case if I go to next activity and come back to the inflated activity. I know about `onSaveInstance` and `onRestoreSaveInstance`. But how do I put view information in a bundle in `onSaveInstanceState`? Please note that my view was generated Dynamically i.e. on button Click and I want to know as of how to preserve the state of my activity.
How do you go about it?

Comment: I am still looking for the solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am thinking that you should implement some kind of logic that helps you restore the state of your `Views`. So you should be designing a class, let say `ViewDetail` that somehow keeps details about the `Views` that you are adding.... type, dimension, etc. This class should implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) so you are able to add it to the `bundle`.

So you will keep an `ArrayList<ViewDetail>`, `myViews` where everytime the user adds a new `View` you create a new `ViewDetail` object that you add to your `myViews` array.

And then save your `Views` and restore them using those objects:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //save your view states
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("MY_VIEWS",myViews);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //get the views back...
    myViews=savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("MY_VIEWS");
    //TODO: add the views back to your Activity
}
```

Comment: How can views be written to a parcel object?

Answer (score 1):

As your application may be killed completely at any moment without noticem you have to provide long term storage off heap memory

You only have to restore all the  views,  if your activity was  terminated (and it can be at any time).  When it is activated again after termination,  it goes through onCreate() method
 -  this would be proper place to restore activity state.

Only callback which is guaranted to be called before your application / activity is destroyed is onPause() - this is a proper place to save views states into long term off-heap storage.

Comment: I am sure the dynamic activity is finished when I hit back.. Is there a way not to finish the activity when the user hits back?

Comment: It depends on memory status - if there is enough memory, it just paused in case your user activates it again soon. ( onResume() will be called )   Another case would be incomming call - this has priority and  also pauses you activity without killing it.  And yet another cause is when phone orientation is changed -  activity will be killed and restarteed, unless you handle it explicitely.   And launcher will force your activity into portait layout when it is going to lock