# How do you save a (user-created) dynamic Layout in Android?

Tags: android, dynamic, save

I have a button on my home screen that will add an edit text field every time it is pushed (I limited it to 20 for best practice). It is basically a small budgeting app.  I want the user to fill in an X amount of dollars in one of the fields. Then, when they are ready, to come back to the app another time and that created EditText is still there filled with the value.  I know how to utilize SharedPerfrences to hold the value. I do not, however, know how to hold that newly created EditText field when the user comes back.

I am acutally going to expand and have a button and a datepicker associated with each EditText field so soon click the button will create three objects, not just one. But I want to get one working first and will apply the principle to the others later. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good candidate for a SQLite database.

For instance, I use a SQLite database to retain and recall the co-ordinates and types of widgets that the user has arranged within my application.

Note that you don't ever want to be trying to store and recall the actual `EditText` `View` object itself. In your database you need to devise your own table format that suits the kind of information you need to store. If you simply need to retain the states of a series of `EditText` fields then this could be as simple as having a table with just one column that contains a string value on each row. To build your UI up again from that database, you'd loop through and create a new instance of `EditText`, and set the text of each one from the table.

Comment: OK, thank you very much.  It looks like I was taking this with the wrong angle.  Although I'd love to simplify this and use SharedPreferences over SQLite but at least you got me on the right track!  I'd love to see how others would attempt this.

Comment: `SharedPreferences` might be an easier way to get started and get something up and running. However, `SharedPreferences` is really for use for storing a small amount of specific key=value data; it's not suited at all for array data. So, if you had just one `EditText` then you could have a single prefs key like `mFieldValue`, but for many `EditText`s you would have to use keys like mFieldValue1, mFieldValue2, etc., or instead group all `EditText`s' values into one value string. Either way is messy and like putting a square peg in a round hole, and it's where a SQLite database comes in.

Comment: Doing some research here based on your recommendation, I am finding that SQLite looks to be the way to go!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use Android `Parcelable` interface, refer to [this](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html) to know as of how to implement it, refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8743236/892055) which I has asked on StackOverflow, it has a good answer.