# Android save programmatically created button

Tags: android

In my program i create buttons programmatically on OnTouch event but when i reopen the app or activity get restarted these button do not appear 
Can any one suggest me how can i create buttons programmatically those will stick to the layout even after the activity gets restart or app gets restart

Comment: save the state of the button in shared pref and then on resume u can check whether button is to be placed or NOt

Answer (score 1):

Use **SharedPreferences** to store coordinates value.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in Comments saving state in shared preferences is good option .
So you can go with this links to know more about this topic, I think it will be more clear when you will look into all this .

[Save instance of dynamically generated views when we switch back and forth between activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743236/save-instance-of-dynamically-generated-views-when-we-switch-back-and-forth-betwe)

[How do you save a (user-created) dynamic Layout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649469/how-do-you-save-a-user-created-dynamic-layout-in-android)

[android save programmatically created views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033619/android-save-programmatically-created-views)

[Android - How to save a programmatically created view and restore it on app restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697105/android-how-to-save-a-programmatically-created-view-and-restore-it-on-app-rest)