# Saving the activity state when rotating the screen

Tags: java, android, rotation

I'm working on an android app, right now I limited the user to only use horizontal view for all activities.

I want to be able to give the user the option to rotate the screen, but when I do that, the activity starts from the beginning instead of just staying the same.

Any idea how to save the state when rotating the screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you have to **override `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)`** within your Activity.

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
```

You also have to edit the appropriate element in your manifest file to include the android:configChanges Just see the code below:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

I also like Marko's idea but it's simply not efficient. This way, we don't have to call onCreate/onStartup/etc. all the time we do a simple rotate. There is no need to "rebuild" the infrastructure from scratch (e.g. getting Views,..)

Comment: Note that the docs suggest not to do it this way, although its how I do it also ;)

Comment: its at official android website, because configChanges="oriantatin|keyboardHidden" doesnt take care of all possible changes, you have plenty more android takes care by default and by overriding it is expected that you take care of them

Comment: @poitroae [Here you go](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) It doesn't say not to use it but it says to use it as a last resort so I guess my original comment was a little misleading but I think its worth noting. But, like I said, that is how I do it and haven't noticed any problems, yet...

Comment: @codeMagic I think this is a perfect application of overriding `configChanges`.

Comment: I agree with you. I just always think it is worth noting what the docs say. I always make that a note when I put this same answer on a similar question. I don't know what resources don't get updated when doing it this way, I just know that's what the docs say. As I said, this is the way I do it also and haven't found any problems from it

Answer (score 3):

Each time you rotate the device, onCreate method is being called again. You can save the values by overriding onSavedInstanceState and get them back in onRestoreInstanceState or in onCreate method. For example lets save boolean(you can save whatever you want):

save the value:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean("booleanValue", true);
}
```

restore the value (you can call this in onCreate as well):

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("booleanValue")) {
            boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("booleanValue");
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: But I want to save the view of the activity not values. I have a table with text  views, if the user click on a textview the text changes, when you flip the screen the textview's text changes to the original one.

Comment: so you get the text of textview like String textViewtext = textview.getText(); then instead of saving boolean you are saving that string.. ?

Comment: or you are dynamically adding textviews?

Comment: dynamically. and I have a list of 50-80 textviews

Comment: maybe this question will help you then, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743236/save-instance-of-dynamically-generated-views-when-we-switch-back-and-forth-betwe

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity (...)
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
          (...)>
```

Adding this to your manifest does not allow Android to restart the activity after chaging the layout.